# Fatal Error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function - on logout of wordpress dashboard

Tags: php, functions

I am getting a fatal error when trying to login to the WP dashboard - and on logout after logging in via the host:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError:
Too few arguments to function Wpsec\captcha\handlers\WPLoginEventHandler::handle_login_hook(), 
1 passed in /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 308 and exactly 2 expected in 
/var/www/wp-content/mu-plugins/vendor/wpsec/wp-captcha-plugin/src/handlers/WPLoginEventHandler.php:24

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): Wpsec\captcha\handlers\WPLoginEventHandler->handle_login_hook(NULL) 
#1 /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#2 /var/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /var/www/wp-content/themes/arya-multipurpose-child/functions.php(34): do_action('wp_login_failed', NULL)
#4 /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): {closure}(NULL, '', '')
#5 /var/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#6 /var/www/wp-includes/pluggable.php(614): apply_filters('authenticate', NULL, '', '')
#7 /var/www/wp-includes/user.php(95): wp_authenticate('', '')
#8 /var/www/wp-login.php in /var/www/wp-content/mu-plugins/vendor/wpsec/wp-captcha-plugin/src/handlers/WPLoginEventHandler.php on line 24
```

However I have only added code to arya-multipurpose-child/functions.php:

```
//add hook to redirect the user back to the elementor login page if the login failed
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'elementor_form_login_fail' );
function elementor_form_login_fail( $username ) {
    $referrer = wp_get_referer();  // where did the post submission come from?
//    $referrer = array();
    // if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
    if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') ) {
        //redirect back to the referrer page, appending the login=failed parameter and removing any previous query strings
        //maybe could be smarter here and parse/rebuild the query strings from the referrer if they are important
        wp_redirect(preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $referrer) . '/?login=failed' );
        exit;
    }
}

add_filter( 'authenticate', function( $user, $username, $password ) {
    // forcefully capture login failed to forcefully open wp_login_failed action, 
    // so that this event can be captured
    if ( empty( $username ) || empty( $password ) ) {
        do_action( 'wp_login_failed', $user );
    }
    return $user;
}, 10, 3 );

// to handle even you can handle the error like
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', function( $username ) {
    if ( is_wp_error( $username ) ) {
        // perform operation on error object for empty error
    }
} );
?>
```

The additions are working as desired on the login form on the home page when there is ANY kind of failed login i.e. redirecting back to the login page while also returning ?login=failed so as to trigger the "Login failed!" message on the page.

However I am struggling to find where I am going wrong with the arguments. Grateful for any help.

Comment: It looks like this error is coming from a security plugin; whichever one uses the namespace `Wpsec` is the one you'll need to ask about this.

Comment: @PatJ I think the issue is due to this line - `do_action( 'wp_login_failed', $user );` - there has to be 2 parameters (`$username` and `$error`) passed to `do_action()` ([see the hook documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login_failed/)), but @incredibull808 only passed one, hence such error happened when a function expects to receive 2 parameters..

Comment: @SallyCJ You're right; I somehow missed the fact they were calling `do_action()` in their code.

Comment: I see it now @SallyCJ - thanks - that also fits the line ref given by the debug. I have modified that line now to: `do_action( 'wp_login_failed', $username, $error );` and am still getting "Notice: Undefined variable: error in /var/www/wp-content/themes/arya-multipurpose-child/functions.php on line 34"
Sorry to ask again but any other thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts too @PatJ

Comment: @incredibull808, that's because you did not define `$error`, so you need to define it before passing it to `do_action()`, e.g. `$error = new WP_Error( 'your_code', 'Username and password are required' );`. But why must you do the "forcefully open wp_login_failed action"? Did you write the `add_filter()` part in your code, and also the last `add_action()` call? What do they solve or do? Have you tried removing them and did doing so cause any issues? If not, then just remove them.

Comment: @SallyCJ so the problem I was having was that if the username or password fields were left empty, the form was redirecting to wp-login.php. I wanted it to redirect back to the home url with login-failed in order to trigger the failed login message. The add_filter () did resolve this. 
I have to confess I am extremely new to this and this was all hacked together with the help of a friend who properly understands php. I think they added the last section as backup for if I came across any further specific login error issues as the site went live.

Comment: @SallyCJ You are quite right if the add_action() call is removed nothing changes. If the add_filter is removed then the user gets dropped to wp-login.php if they leave a field empty. 
Ultimately I have opted to define $error as an empty string and remove the add_action() which I will bear in mind. Thanks so much for your time

Comment: "*I have opted to define $error as an empty string*" - **don't do that**, it should be an instance of the `WP_Error` class, just as you could see in my previous comment. And actually, if all you wanted to do is to redirect the user to the home page if the username or password is empty, then the hook that you should use is [`wp_authenticate`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_authenticate/) - and with that, you can replace all the snippets in your question with something that's simple and not hacky like [this](https://gist.github.com/5ally/306a3933f5efb6524ec95f7460c504f8).

Comment: That's so helpful thank you @SallyCJ